# JS uses to different paddings

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am having a problem with my website.
The padding-top of div class="row slide-content" is acting weird.
For some slides it is about 223px and for other slides it uses a different padding.

PHP

```
<div class="home-slider">
            <ul class="slides">

                <?php while ($slide =& $loop->next()): ?>

                    <li>
                        <div class="row slide-content">
                            <div class="large-10 large-centered columns text-center">                                                             
                                                      <?php if ( ! empty( $slide->button ) ) : ?>


                                        <div class="SLIDERLOGO"><?php echo $slide->button; ?> </div>


                                <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php if ( ! empty( $slide->ititle ) || ! empty( $slide->caption ) ) : ?>

                                    <div class="hero-title">
                                        <div class="large-3 columns nopad border-bottom"></div>
                                        <div class="large-6 columns text-center">

                                            <?php if ( ! empty( $slide->ititle ) ) : ?>

                                                <h4 class="text-white alt-h"><?php echo $slide->ititle; ?></h4>

                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                        </div>

                                        <?php if ( empty( $slide->ititle ) ) : ?>

                                                <div class="large-6 columns nopad border-bottom"></div>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <div class="large-3 columns nopad border-bottom"></div>
                                        <h1 class="text-white"><?php echo $slide->caption; ?></h1>
                                    </div><!--end of hero title-->

                                <?php endif; ?>



                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <img class="slider-bg" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $slide->alt ); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_attr( $slide->img ); ?>" />
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>


            </ul>
        </div><!--end of Home slider-->
```

The logo is inserted here

```
<?php echo $slide->button; ?>
```

Both logo's are exactly the same dimensions

JS
// Append HTML 's as CSS Background for slides
    // also center the content of the slide

```
jQuery('.home-slider .slides li').each(function () {

    var imgSrc = jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').attr('src');
    jQuery(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').remove();

    var slideHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    var contentHeight = jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').height();
    var padTop = (slideHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2);

    jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').css('padding-top', padTop);

});
```

this is the link to my website
http://timberlife.nl

It wont happen every time but sometimes the padding between the logo and the top of the page changes. I hope i have explained wel enough :)

Many thanks!
Daan

Comment: Might not be directly related to your problem, but – your HTML code is quite a mess, you should go fix those errors. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://timberlife.nl/

Comment: hmm is see. Thanks for noticing me. Only i have no idea where to find these errors. And is it really a problem when i leave it like this? Is it bad SEO for example?

Answer (score 0):

I've run the code with the debugger on and can get the padding to -8px. I think this is because the jQuery document.ready function doesn't wait for images to download and so your li element doesn't have the height you expect.

Can you wrap your jQuery function in the following code to see if waiting until the images have loaded fixes the issue?

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
}
```

Comment: like this?

    $(window).bind("load", function() {
jQuery('.home-slider .slides li').each(function () {

    var imgSrc = jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').attr('src');
    jQuery(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').remove();

    var slideHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    var contentHeight = jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').height();
    var padTop = (slideHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2);

    jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').css('padding-top', padTop);

});
}

Comment: Because if i do so, the page wont load at all :P